# How can I figure out what is making my Wordpress site so slow?

Tags: performance, hosting, troubleshooting

My site, which is small and only just recently launched, is pretty damn slow when it comes to doing admin stuff. What tools/techniques can I use to help narrow down whether the slowness is due to my host, theme (I'm using Divi), plugins, etc.?

For example, should I open up developer tools and see how long certain requests to the server are taking? If so, what should I look for and how should I interpret the results? Also, should I deactivate plugins one at a time and then perform the same action to see the result? Or does deactivating a plugin not completely eliminate the plugin as the source of the problem (i.e., do deactivated plugins still have some kind of footprint or effect on the site)?

Comment: When you say "slow doing admin stuff" do you mean the site itself performs fine, it's just the admin pages? Is the main site cached or served through a CDN? Deactivating plugins shouldn't have any footprint, no. In the first instance it's probably worth working out where the bottleneck is: is it CPU or memory load on your web server (or server process), or CPU or memory load on the database, or network access to your server if it's just an origin server, or anything else obvious. It is worth looking at the volume of database traffic at least, yes.

Comment: Make a copy of the site (so you're not testing on production) and use plugins such as Debug Toolbar, Query Debug, PPP, etc.

Comment: A single poorly coded plugin can slow down the admin side of a site, yes. Use a process of elimination.

Comment: @Rup, Yes, the site performance itself is okay (I haven't yet implemented caching but I plan to do that) but clicking around in the Dashboard and especially loading up pages to edit takes way longer than it should, IMO. I'm wondering if it's the Divi theme, which recently had a major update. That's always been kind of slow but it definitely seems worse now. Thanks all for the suggestions.

Comment: Also make sure you're using PHP 7+. That should help.